# What do the 2 values for Firebase hosting stored bytes mean?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-console

I'm talking about the chart found in the console, in Hosting > Usage > Storage.

I know that the storage volume is supposed to be the size used by the hosting. and it's for all versions, that are NOT deleted by default.

My problem is that I have 2 non continuous series on the chart. There are some days with 1 value, some days with 2 values, and some days with 0 values!

Here is a screenshot

[image: multiple storage values]

Edit: Not sure if it's linked to the problem, but that could be interesting info for debugging. That project is now on a Blaze plan but hosting storage was over 1 GB when it was still on a Spark plan.

Comment: It's a glitch, there shouldn't be two numbers there.

Comment: OK. So what number are you billed on with this "feature"? Or is it the sum of both? Makes no difference here, just curious.

Comment: Any idea on how there can be days without a value?

Comment: We'll have to investigate -- this is a bug and we'll have to do some research to figure out the cause and which number is the accurate one. It is likely *not* the sum of the two, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Sounds like an answer @MichaelBleigh! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in the Firebase Hosting console that is currently being investigated by the team. There should only be one line. We hope to address it in the near future.

Comment: See edit. It was over 1 GB on the free plan, which should not be possible. But I don't know if you really enforce that, considering you charge less than $0.03 per GB of storage.